# Window Feature FEATURE_LEFT_ICON with ExpandableListActivity is not working

Tags: android

I am using API 10 GingerBread

I am not using a layout, although I did try this with a layout and it still doesn't work. Works fine with a normal Activity subclass, I don't see what the problem is.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

For what it is worth, using FEATURE_NO_TITLE works fine. What gives? Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/G_5MAq8v4jc

Answer (score 4):

Try this code...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
setContentView(R.layout.main); //or whatever layout is shows
setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```